# Read multiple XML text values using XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl

I started learning the
[`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) module
but I can't understand how to read tags and fetch the data for my use.

Below is my attempt to parse a small section from an XML file. I want to pick a comma-separated list of the text content of `customfieldvalue` elements.

Output for example should be like:

```
print "customfieldvalue are = $myvalues \n";
# customfieldvalue are = UNIX,PERL
```

I am stuck after reading the XML section, Please help meto achieve this.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml   = new XML::Simple;
my $cdata = join('', <DATA>);

my $data = $xml->XMLin($cdata, KeyAttr => ['id']);
print Dumper($cdata);

__DATA__
<customfield id="customfield_66440" key="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multiselect">
  <customfieldname>Program</customfieldname>
  <customfieldvalues>
    <customfieldvalue key="125160"><![CDATA[UNIX]]></customfieldvalue>
    <customfieldvalue key="125160"><![CDATA[PERL]]></customfieldvalue>
  </customfieldvalues>
</customfield>
```

Comment: `XMLin` and `KeyAttr` come from [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple), not [XML::Parser](http://p3rl.org/XML::Parser).

Comment: Sorry, thanks for highlighting. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

[XML::Simple says](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) to use [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) instead.

```
use XML::LibXML qw();

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => \<<'XML');
<customfield id="customfield_66440" key="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multiselect">
    <customfieldname>Program</customfieldname>
    <customfieldvalues>
        <customfieldvalue key="125160"><![CDATA[UNIX]]></customfieldvalue>
        <customfieldvalue key="125160"><![CDATA[PERL]]></customfieldvalue>

    </customfieldvalues>
</customfield>
XML

my @values = map { $_->textContent } $dom->findnodes('//customfieldvalue');
# ("UNIX", "PERL")
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. but XML::LibXML not found/installed :-(

Comment: `XML::Twig` may be installed - that's another common choice. But no XML parsers are 'core' (not even `XML::Simple`).